# how to overlap a canvas over a table

Tags: html, css

How can I overlap a canvas over a table as shown in the picture? The yellow part is the canvas where I want to insert images like 'multiplication' and 'equal'.

[image]

```
<canvas id="canvasminus" class="wrapper"></canvas>
<table id="table" align="center" class="wrapper">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
</table>
```

```
canvasminus{
    z-index:1;
    margin:auto;
}

#table {
    z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper
{
    position:relative;    
}
```

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been obsolete for several years: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: what exact UI are you after? This seems to be too broad for someone to attempt to solve.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph hi, ive alr updated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 10px);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<table border="collapse">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid #000000;background:red;">
</canvas>
      <div>12</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid #000000;background:red;">
</canvas>
      <div>12</div>
    </td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid #000000;background:red;">
</canvas>
      <div>1</div>
    </td>
    <td> <canvas id="myCanvas" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid #000000;background:red;">
</canvas>
      <div>2</div>
    </td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```